# How to use NAnt to build with Azure DevOps and Git?

Tags: git, command-line, build, azure-devops, nant

We have NAnt builds set up that currently pulls the source code from TFS via the command line.  We are switching over to Azure DevOps and from what I understand, the source code provider is Git.  I need to figure out how to pull down the latest code via a command line as we did with TFS.

I've researched everywhere and while I can see some Git command line options, I'm not sure how or what to use with NAnt.

What I need to replace looks something like this:

```
get TFSProjectName /recursive /version:${alterVersion} /login:userName, password
```

Could you please advise me on the build options with Azue DevOps?

Answer (score 0):

You can add following content for get the source from TFS. More details about the command parameter, please see this document(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/get-command?view=azure-devops).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="TFUse_GetFiles" default="GetTFSFiles">
<target name="GetTFSFiles" >
  <exec program="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe">
<arg value="get" />
    <arg value="/recursive" />
    <arg value="/login:username,password " />
    <arg value="$/Projects/dir/Main" />
<arg value="/force" />
  </exec>
</target> 
</project>
```

If you turned to use Git, please refer to Git command(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/command-prompt?view=azure-devops).  You can use pull or fetch command to update the code. Before using the git for Azure DevOps, you need to be  authenticated with Azure Repos (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/auth-overview?view=azure-devops).